# In Azure Terraform, how to create a VM from a .iso file

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I followed https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=terraform+azure+youtube&docid=608046594389512095&mid=B2B5F7B1992184605AD7B2B5F7B1992184605AD7&view=detail&FORM=VIRE
and I am running terraform from azure cli. 
The above link created a VM that had ubuntu OS and had apache running on it. But I need the VM to be loaded from an iso file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create the Azure VM from an iso file. In Azure, you only can create the VM from the managed image or the image provided by the Azure platform, you can create the VHD file locally from the iso file and make it match the rules of Azure and upload the VHD file to Azure storage, and then create the unmanaged VM from it. Here is an [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-an-azure-vm-from-the-vhdxvhd-file/) that creates Azure VM from the VHD file.